Simple VAD implementation in CCS
I am getting an error while trying to implement this VAD (Voice Activity Detection) in C using CCS.
I think fread function is not working properly because I am getting num_frames = 1 each time I run it and consequently only frame 0 is considered by the VAD.
Here is my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FRAME_SIZE 256    // Frame size in samples
#define SAMPLE_RATE 16000 // Sample rate in Hz
#define THRESHOLD 1e7     // Energy threshold

double compute_energy(const short *frame, int frame_size)
{
    double energy = 0.0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < frame_size; ++i)
    {
        double val = frame[i];
        energy += val * val;
    }
    return energy;
}

void vad(const short *audio_data, int num_samples)
{
    int num_frames = num_samples / FRAME_SIZE;

    printf("NUM FRAMES: %d", num_frames);

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < num_frames; ++i)
    {
        printf("i VALUE: %d", i);

        // Extract frame
        const short *frame = &audio_data[i * FRAME_SIZE];

        // Compute energy
        double energy = compute_energy(frame, FRAME_SIZE);

        // Make decision
        if (energy > THRESHOLD)
        {
            printf("Frame %d: Speech (Energy: %f)\n", i, energy);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Frame %d: Silence (Energy: %f)\n", i, energy);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    // File path to the .raw audio file
    const char *file_path = "../example.raw"; // Ensure this is the correct file name

    // Open the file
    FILE *file = fopen(file_path, "rb");
    if (!file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s': %s\n", file_path, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // Seek to the end of the file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

    // Get the current file position
    long filesize = ftell(file);

    // Print the file size
    printf("Size of file: %ld bytes\n", filesize);

    // Seek back to the beginning of the file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Allocate memory for one frame of audio data
    char *audio_data = (char *)malloc(FRAME_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    if (!audio_data)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate memory");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    int num_samples = fread(audio_data, sizeof(char), FRAME_SIZE, file);

    if (num_samples == 0 && ferror(file))
    {
        perror("Failed to read from file");
        free(audio_data);
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    while (num_samples > 0)
    {
        printf("TEST ENTER VAD\n");

        // Perform VAD
        vad(audio_data, num_samples);
    }
    fclose(file);

    // Free memory
    free(audio_data);

    return 0;
}


I expect to see many frames being evaluated by VAD

while (num_samples > 0) Do you expect this loop to terminate? num_samples never changes.

&audio_data[i * FRAME_SIZE]; You only allocate memory for 1 frame. Whenever i is not 0 you will perform an out of bounds access. You also only read 1 frame from the file. How do you expect to get num_frames different from 1 with these proconditions?

frame_size / FRAME_SIZE will 1 or 0.

You seem to intent to read the whole file at once as you retrieve the size of it via ftell. Then you should change fread(audio_data, sizeof(char), FRAME_SIZE, file); to fread(audio_data, FRAME_SIZE, filesize / FRAME_SIZE, file); which will then return number of frames, not number of bytes read.

Binary streams are not required to support SEEK_END. sizeof(char) is always 1 by definition.
